# Combining events in WPF & F# (or, am I going crazy?)

Tags: wpf, events, f#

Playing with a spike, I'm trying to drag a WPF label around. I translated Don Syme's `mkMouseTracker` code from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/03/24/fsharpcompositionalevents.aspx), and it looks like it should work, but for some reason, there is never any difference between the two args returned from `mouseEvent`, so my label never moves.

`printf`ing seems to show that the `last` parameter gets swallowed/replaced with the values from moveArgs. Is this something to do with the use of `ref`?

Sorry the code block is a bit long, but it is self-contained.

```
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "System.Xaml"

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Controls

let window = new Window(Name="Test",Width=500.0,Height=500.0)
window.Visibility <- Visibility.Visible
window.Show()

let l = new System.Windows.Controls.Label(Height = 30., Width = 150., 
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, BorderThickness = Thickness(3.))
window.Content <- l

let mkMouseTracker (c : #UIElement) =
  let event = new Event<_>()
  let lastArgs = ref None
  c.MouseDown.Add(fun args -> lastArgs := Some (args :> Input.MouseEventArgs ))
  c.MouseUp  .Add(fun args -> lastArgs := None)
  c.MouseMove.Add(fun moveArgs ->
    match !lastArgs with
    | Some last -> event.Trigger(last,moveArgs); lastArgs := Some moveArgs
    | None -> ())
  event.Publish

let mouseEvent = mkMouseTracker l
mouseEvent.Add(fun (args1, args2) ->
    let pos1, pos2 = args1.GetPosition(l), args2.GetPosition(l)
    l.RenderTransform <- TranslateTransform(pos2.X - pos1.X, pos2.Y - pos1.Y)
    l.Content <- sprintf "%A: %A -> %A" args1.Timestamp pos1 pos2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to get the position of the event immediately after the event is triggered. It is quite possible that WPF is re-using the mutable `MouseEventArgs` object for all the events (or something like that), so calling `GetPosition` later gives you the same point.

The following code does *something*. It doesn't work completely - the label is moved to a wrong place, so it still needs to be fixed, but it should get you started :-).

```
let mkMouseTracker (e : #UIElement) =
  let event = new Event<_>()
  let lastArgs = ref None
  e.MouseDown.Add(fun args -> lastArgs := Some(args.GetPosition(e)))
  e.MouseUp  .Add(fun args -> lastArgs := None)
  e.MouseMove.Add(fun moveArgs ->
    match !lastArgs with
    | Some last -> 
        let pos = moveArgs.GetPosition(e)
        event.Trigger(last,pos)
        lastArgs := Some pos
    | None -> ())
  event.Publish

let mouseEvent = mkMouseTracker l
mouseEvent.Add(fun (pos1, pos2) ->
    l.RenderTransform <- TranslateTransform(pos2.X - pos1.X, pos2.Y - pos1.Y)
    l.Content <- sprintf "%A" (pos2.X - pos1.X, pos2.Y - pos1.Y))
```

Comment: Tick 'cos it's the answer, and +1 'cos it means I'm *not* crazy :)

Comment: ILSpy says that GetPosition internally makes call to directly to MouseDevice without picking current coordinates. Since it's likely that MouseDevice is the same in both instances of event args, then this explains current behavior.